# In Radius of Curvature calculation why do I have to assume $\text{d}^2x/\text{d}t^2=0$?

Tags: kinematics, differentiation

Recently, I was calculating the radius of curvature of projectile trajectories at certain points. There are two ways to do the same:

1. Given the velocity and acceleration of the particle at some point, $R=\frac{v^2}{a_{\perp}}$.
2. Given the equation of the trajectory $(x,f(x))$, we can find $R=\left(1+ \left(\frac{\rm dy}{\rm dx}\right)^2\right)^{3/2} / \,\,\,\frac{\rm d^2y}{\rm dx^2}$.

Since I knew the derivation of both the parts individually, I tried to directly show their equivalence. So I tried to obtain (2) from (1). Since the position of the particle is $$\vec{s} =x\vec{i}+f(x)\vec j,$$ we can easily find the velocity at each point as follows,
$$\vec v=\frac{\rm{d}\vec{s}}{\rm dt}=\frac{\rm dx}{\rm dt}\cdot \left(\vec i + \frac{\rm df}{\rm dx}\vec j\right),$$ and the acceleration then will be,
$$\vec a=\frac{\rm d \vec v}{\rm dt}=\frac{\rm d^2x}{\rm dt^2}\vec i + \frac{\rm d^2f}{\rm dt^2}\vec j.$$ Using dot product, a unit vector that is perpendicular to $\vec v$ is given by,
$$\vec u = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{\rm df}{\rm dx}\right)^2}}\cdot \left(-\frac{\rm df}{\rm dx}\vec i + \vec j\right).$$ Finally, we can calculate,

$$R=\frac{|\vec v|^2}{\vec a \cdot \vec u}=
\frac{\left(\frac{\rm dx}{\rm dt}\right)^2\cdot \left(1 + \left(\frac{\rm df}{\rm dx}\right)^2\right)}{ \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{\rm df}{\rm dx}\right)^2}}\cdot \left(-\frac{\rm df}{\rm dx}\cdot \frac{\rm d^2x}{\rm dt^2} + \left(\frac{\rm dx}{\rm dt}\right)^2\cdot \frac{\rm d^2f}{\rm dx^2}\right)}
=\left(1+ \left(\frac{\rm df}{\rm dx}\right)^2\right)^{3/2} / \,\,\,\frac{\rm d^2f}{\rm dx^2}$$

except that the last equality only seems to hold if $-\frac{\rm df}{\rm dx}\cdot \frac{\rm d^2x}{\rm dt^2} =0$. Where am I going wrong? (The assumption is valid for projectile paths since then $x=(u_{\rm initial}\cos\theta)\cdot t$ but I would assume this line of reasoning should work in the general case too).

Comment: Check your calculation for $\vec a \cdot \vec u$. You should have an additional term.

Comment: @GiorgioP Sorry, but I am unable to catch my error. There should be two terms only, right (since the vectors are 2D)?

Comment: Try to re-evaluate the $\vec j$ component of the acceleration in terms of derivative of $f$ wrt $x$ and time derivatives of $x(t)$.